# Will this cause any memory leaks, in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, memory-leaks

I was stuck at this problem for a long time now.

I want to create a nested hash. Earlier I used to do this:

```
a = {}

a[x_id] ||= {}
a[x_id][y_id] || = {}
a[x_id][y_id] = z_value
```

Then I came to stackoverflow and found this soultion:

```
a = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) } #highlighted line
a[x_id][y_id] = z_value
```

Now, I didn't understand the "highlighted line". But when I implemented it, it worked.

Now, the question is how, and more importantly, will this cause any memory leaks in the future with more data, or with more nesting for that matter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of memory-leaks, or at the very least how it applies to Ruby (or more accurately, how is *doesn't* apply).

Ruby uses a garbage collector, which handles freeing memory for you when an object goes out of scope (i.e. no longer any existing reference to it). Unless you are allocating memory yourself like what you would do in C, you do not need to concern yourself with freeing it.

In Ruby, unless you are using the C API, using Fiddle/FFI to call external code (in some cases), or perhaps a few other edge cases, you do not need to worry about freeing memory. Simply letting an object go out of scope will accomplish the same task internally.

Assuming you may have just been using an inaccurate term, and really mean "storing more and more worthless objects that won't be used again", then that is an implementation question that your example does not make clear.

If perhaps you mean, for example...

```
hash[x][y] = z
```

...and then later you perform the same action, wondering if the old `z` value is building up memory, then "no", its not (assuming `x` and `y` are the same). As mentioned above, storing a new value to the same place causes the old object that was there to go out of scope, and Ruby will free its memory internally as long as it is not referenced anywhere else.